# Best way to execute repetitive Spring controller code?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, spring, spring-mvc

I have a library method `Common.addTheUsualStuffToTheModel(model)` that needs to add various attributes to the model **in every controller method in my app**.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/everypath", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public final String everyHandler(ModelMap model)
{
    model = Common.addTheUsualStuffToTheModel(model);
    return "everyPage";
}
```

So far I have been adding this same line to every handler method:

```
    model = Common.addTheUsualStuffToTheModel(model);
```

But I'm afraid this is not consistent with the principle of "write once, use everywhere".

How do I avoid repeating this code in every handler?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an [interceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/HandlerInterceptorAdapter.html) and [`<mvc:interceptors>`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-interceptors) to do that

In your interceptor you can add anything as request attribute (which is in fact where the model attributes go). The interceptor code is executed before or after each method (that matches the interceptor mapping).

If you don't necessarily need the model to be populated *before* the controller method, in the `postHandle` method you get the `ModelAndView` object.

Comment: Nice, it looks like with the postHandleRender method you can even get a hold of the model and add stuff before the view is rendered, so you wouldn't have to add it as a request attribute.

Comment: sorry, I have given the wrong link - it should be the `servlet`, not `portlet`. The servlet has only 3 methods, where the model is available only in the postHandle method.

Comment: @digitaljoel yup, added that.

Answer (score 0):

What about specifying @ModelAttribute annotated reference data provider methods.  If you had a base class for all of your controllers, and that base class had @ModelAttribute annotated methods then I believe that data would be available in the model for all views handled by those controllers.  Have a look at [15.3.2.8 in the Spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html).